# Java application that connects to a PIC microcontroller and lights a LED

Tags: java, connection, usb, microcontroller, pic

I am undergoing a project that is supposed to make a java application with a series of buttons that when they are pressed they light up individual LEDs.

I have found a previous project that has an android app that connects via USB a tablet and the PIC microcontroller.When the user taps one of the buttons on the tablet interface the respective LED on a test board that is connected to the PIC microcontroller lights up.

I want to connect the USB from the PIC microcontroller into a PC directly and make a java application that resembles the one on the tablet.

So,my question is:Can it be done? And if it can,what library should i use to identify the PIC controller connected to the PC via USB and send input to light the LED.

Regards,
Alexander

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: you need a serial lib for the asynch communication

Comment: Well until now i struggled to make the tablet project work because the documentation was incomplete and the test board and microcontroller are old.2 days ago i made sure that both android app and microcontroller work properly and  until today i have searched different PIC documentations and connection tutorials but none were suffice to make me understand the architecture so before i go first hand with the few informations i had i wanted to ask you guys about it, keeping in account that i have solved almost all my questions about coding on this site.

Answer (score 0):

if your PC is on linux you can check what USB class is implemented on the PIC using `lsusb -v`. if it implements USB CDC ACM (**virtual COM port**) this is easy because in this case you can use a standard RS-232 library in java to communicate with the PIC. It is common that test boards implement a virtual COM ....

on windows you can use a tool like `USBDeview` or `USBView` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560019(v=vs.85).aspx) to get this information.
There is also a port of `libusb` for windows